# Google Analytics Event track HTML Select box

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Does anyone know if it is possible to add Google Analytics event tracking to HTML select boxes to get unique tracking for each of the options within the select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select onchange="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category','Action', this.value);">
```

will track an event with the value of the select option as value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select onchange="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category','Action', this.value]);">
                                                                           ^
```

Forgot the closing bracket **`]`**... the original code causes syntax error